# My phone gives me charge load for my bluetooth headset why wont my mac?

Tags: bluetooth, charging

My phone gives me charge load for my Bluetooth headset why won't my mac ?

I couldn't find an app for that specific need.
I've only seen [this Q&A on apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7879779) on this very topic:
Any pointers ?
(my headset is a JBL T450BT ; my phone an android one; mac model is macbook pro 13" 2019, with 4 USB-C ports)

Comment: What Mac? (Model and OS version)

Comment: Edited question to give this info

Comment: There's no native way to do this.  The best thing to do is to put in a feature request directly with Apple https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html  If enough people do this, they will probably add it in